# external link getting appended with localhost url

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to redirect users to external links but the following code is always

```
<a href={`"https://"${posts.ctaURL1}`}
```

redirecting users to http://localhost:8080/%22https://%22www.fb.com

The external link won't be necessary https it can be http as well and url is dynamically filled. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Typo: You have some rogue `"` characters in your template string. (Probably left over from a time when it was a string literal)

Answer (score 1):

change your code to

```
const url = 'www.google.com'

<a href={`//${url}`}> 
   Go to external site
</a>
```

This will produce what you exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to check for the url if it has :// or not.
For example in angular, you could do:

```
  setURL(link: string): string {
     return link.includes("://") ? link : '//' + link;
   }
```

And in the html, you could use it like this:

```
<a [href]="setURL(link)" target="_blank">{{ link }}</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that `posts.ctaURL1` also contains `https`, so that's why you get such a strange url. You could try

```
<a href={posts.ctaURL1}>click here</a>
```

If you want to replace `https` with `http` you can use string replace.

```
let url = posts.ctaURL1.replace("https", "http")
<a href={url}>click here</a>
```

Comment: Without adding https, link is going to http://localhost:8082/www.fb.com.

Comment: Can you add the content of `posts.ctaURL1` to your question? Then we can replicate your problem and see what's going wrong.